# Npm modules of validation in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there a module for performing validation in core mongodb driver of node.js. Similary how mongoose does it. As I would require mongodb in a new client project instead of monoose.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB introduced validation in collections in version 3.2 -

> MongoDB provides the capability to validate documents during updates and insertions. Validation rules are specified on a per-collection basis using the validator option, which takes a document that specifies the validation rules or expressions.

You can read more about it in the official docs of MongoDB [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/).

As far as Node.js MongoDB driver is concerned, then it will also provide this feature out of the box. No need to install any other module. You can check [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/collections/) official tutorial which shows you how to use the Node.js driver to set up validation.

Keep in mind one thing that *Mongoose* provides you with application level validation so you save on the round trip time as you don't need to go to the Mongo database to validate your data. Whereas the native validation is provided by the Mongo Database itself hence a round trip would be necessary from your application to your Mongo Database to validate the data.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It works but always gives the same message for all validation errors. This also a open issue in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20547.

Comment: I see. Not sure it will be resolved soon. I don't need that information thus I'm able to use it.